# Tools to convert between assembly and hex in windows?

Tags: assembly, hex

Can `cl.exe` or `link.exe` do the job?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by assembly ? 
the assembly language ?
like

```
mov eax,4
mov ebx,3
```

and if so what do you mean by converting this into hex ? 
if you want to view binary file in hex you can use [hex editor](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm)

you can use [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 
if the file name is source.s
then use

```
gcc source.s
```

Comment: Yes,I need a tool to convert between these two automatically.

Comment: o i think i know what you mean , you want to assembly the file. you can use link i think you can use gcc. i have edited mt answer.